# Google Child Form created in an other Google Parent Form with both OnSubmit Trigger create strange behavior on the child submit triggering

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

First of all, sorry for the not so explicit title, but the problem that I am meeting is quite strange.

When someone answer to a particular Google Parent Form, I am creating a child form based on a template. To this new form, I am adding an OnSubmit Trigger [thanks to this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit).

Here is the minimal code to reproduce the error :

```
function onSendForm(event) {
        let newForm = FormApp.create('A form');

        let trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSendNewForm')
          .forForm(newForm)
          .onFormSubmit()
          .create();
     }
     
function onSendNewForm(event) {
      Logger.log(event.authMode); //Log: FULL
      Logger.log(event.triggerUid); //Log: a normal triggerUid
      Logger.log(event.source.getId()); //Log: The parent form and not the child form (wut ?)
      Logger.log(event.source.getResponses()); //Log: The responses of the parent form (logical from the above log)
      Logger.log(event.response); //throw exception
    }
```

```
    Exception: Aucune réponse portant le numéro XXXXX n'existe pour ce formulaire.
```

So the exception is in french but to translate it, it basically means **"No answer with the id XXXXX is existing for this form"**.

Which is pretty logical as it is looking for a response that is not in the event.source form...

More info:

When I create the form and the trigger in onSendForm(), no problem happens : my form is created, but the trigger is created inside the parent form (and not inside the child form). However, the triggering has the expected behavior :

- it triggers when the child form is sent
- it doesn't trigger when the parent form is sent

I've created many child forms and all of the triggers end up in the AppScript of the parents form. The only problem in the event object that is wrong.

Am I missing something ? Or there is a problem ?

Regards,
coooola

Answer (score 0):

You really only need one onFormSubmit Trigger:

Let's say that you have two forms we will call them formOne and formTwo and let's say that formOne reports it's information to the Sheet named FormOne Response and that formTwo reports it's information to the Sheet named FormTwo Response.  Let's say that when formOne gets submitted that you want to run functionOne() and when formTwo gets submitted you want to run functionTwo(),

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const fObj = {"FormOne Response": 1, "FormTwo Response": 2];
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(fObj[sh.getName()] == 1) {
    functionOne(e);
  } else if ( fObj[sh.getName()] == 2) {
    functionTwo(e):
  }
```

Using code to capture the event object for a spreadsheet:

```
function myMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}

{"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Timestamp":["8/26/2021 5:32:55"],"COL2":["2"],"COL1":["6"]},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":19,"rowStart":19},"source":{},"triggerUid":"7174592604","values":["8/26/2021 5:32:55","6","2"]}
```

Please note the range parameter in the above JSON

Comment: Hello,
It doesn't solve my problem. I've tryed to have the same submit function for the parent form and the child form. The exception is still raised when I try to access e.response.
I'll edit my answer to remove the code that is not useful to create th problem.

Comment: Moreover, there is no `range` parameter in the `event` object I get `onFormSubmit`.

Comment: There is a range parameter in the onFormSubmit for a spreadsheet